# Why DOB logging every time whether updated or not during update API in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, date-parsing

I am logging fields which will be update during update API call.
But getting DOB field every time whether it is updating or not

DOB is of Date type

```
private Date DOB;
```

Logging DOB VALUE when passing this in payload `{ "DOB": "1990-01-01"}`

```
dob: Mon Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1990
Updated Fields during request: DOB
```

is it because it has time also? Though I'm getting same time on every request, still, it is printing that DOB is updated even when value was same and not updated. Why so?

And if I am passing DOB in payload (postman) like this:

```
 "DOB": "20101212"

//it is printing only this 1970 value on log console
dob: Thu Jan 01 11:05:01 IST 1970
```

How can I handle these situations?

Code

```
public static class Updater {
  private final OrgEmployeeMap existing;
  private final EmployeeInformation information;
  private final Set<String> updatedFields = new HashSet<>();

  public Updater(OrgEmployeeMap existing, EmployeeInformation information) {
    this.existing = existing;
    this.information = information;
  }

  public <T> Updater update(String fieldName,
                            Function<EmployeeInformation, T> newValueGetter,
                            Function<OrgEmployeeMap, T> oldValueGetter,
                            BiConsumer<OrgEmployeeMap, T> oldValueSetter) {
    final var newValue = newValueGetter.apply(information);
    final var oldValue = oldValueGetter.apply(existing);
    if (newValue == null || newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
      return this;
    }
    this.updatedFields.add(fieldName);
    oldValueSetter.accept(existing, newValue);
    return this;
  }

  public Set<String> getUpdatedFields() {
    return updatedFields;
  }
}
private void updateExistingEmployee(OrgEmployeeMap existingOrgEmployee, RequestMessage requestMessage) {
    try {
        EmployeeInformation employeeInfo = requestMessage.getData().get(0).getDemographicData().getEmployeeInformation().get(0);
        final var updater = new Updater(existingOrgEmployee, employeeInfo);

        updater
            .update("FirstName", EmployeeInformation::getEmployeeFirstName, OrgEmployeeMap::getFirstName, OrgEmployeeMap::setFirstName)
            .update("LastName", EmployeeInformation::getEmployeeLastName, OrgEmployeeMap::getLastName, OrgEmployeeMap::setLastName)
            .update("DOB", EmployeeInformation::getDOB, OrgEmployeeMap::getDob, OrgEmployeeMap::setDob)
            .update("Gender", EmployeeInformation::getGender, OrgEmployeeMap::getGender, OrgEmployeeMap::setGender)
            .update("Email", EmployeeInformation::getEmail, OrgEmployeeMap::getEmail, OrgEmployeeMap::setEmail);

        final var modifiedFields = updater.getUpdatedFields();
        if (!modifiedFields.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Updated employee : " + String.join(", ", modifiedFields));
        }

        orgEmployeeMapRepository.save(existingOrgEmployee);

        log.info("Updated Employee : " + existingOrgEmployee);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        log.error("error in processing the request error", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("An unexpected error occurred: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

dto class

```
@Data
public class EmployeeInformation {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Email")
    private String Email;

    @JsonProperty(value = "EmployeeFirstName")
    private String EmployeeFirstName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "EmployeeLastName")
    private String EmployeeLastName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "DOB")
    private Date DOB;

..
}
```

model class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeMap {
@Id
    @Column(name = "Id", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String Id;

    @Column(name = "firstName", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "dob", nullable = false)
    private Date dob;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to debug code that you don't bother posting?

Comment: @ArfurNarf Updated code, though I guess code is working fine, there is some issue with Date data type still not sure how can I handle this.

Comment: I suggest you stop using `java.util.Date` and switch to the `java.time` API.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yeah I tried with ```LocalDate DataType``` and it worked for me, this comes under ```java.time```, Thanks 
But it has a restriction of Date format to ```yyyy-mm-dd``` only and my request from payload is going in this format ```yyyymmdd```

Comment: You should **never** log DOB. Or any [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter#BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE) (which corresponds to yyyyMMdd pattern) to parse your date string, 20101212 to a `LocalDate`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("20101212", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-12-12
```

Based on this description, you can make the following changes in your code:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "DOB")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private LocalDate DOB;
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I would focus a bit on the lines

```
if (newValue == null || newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
  return this;
}
this.updatedFields.add(fieldName);
```

For some reason the updatedField.add(...) is called every time for dob.
So what may be happening that newValue is either null or equals does not work as expected. Apply a debugging session or add more log output so you understand why that comparison fails.

Comment: Or more simply `if (Objects.equals(newValue, oldValue))`